# msssql-jdbc: APPARENT DEADLOCK when running integration tests

Tags: jdbc, mssql-jdbc

My application is a spring boot application and using mssql-jdbc (6.1.0.jre8) to connect to an Azure SQL Database.  However, when I run the integration tests I get the following error:

> com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@641c9759
>   -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!

So I did a jstack and see a few RUNNABLE threads:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 [...]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
 - locked <0x00000006c1d34e58> (a java.lang.Object)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
 [...]
 at com.wk.neo.components.reports.ReportRepoImpl.getReport(ReportRepoImpl.java:42)
```

Looking for Threads that are waiting on 0x00000006c1d34e58 lock I see a few threads BLOCKED trying to close its connection:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2418)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000006c1d34e58> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
    [...]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.close(SQLServerStatement.java:662)
```

Why am I I seeing a lot of BLOCKED threads waiting on another thread before they can close their connection? All these threads are read-only queries so I'm confused why am I see this lock contention?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without code it is impossible to tell. It looks like you are sharing a single connection on multiple threads. JDBC connections are supposed to be thread-safe, so internally the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver is probably doing some locking/synchronization to ensure it is thread-safe; that is nothing to do with it being read-only connections.

Comment: I'm using spring boot with JPA so all the connection management is abstracted away from me.  So i'm injecting the PersistenceContext and calling: entityMgr.createNativeSQL(sql);

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the driver to the latest version, the Deadlock exception went away!  Thanks again for the help!